# TimePicker for HH:MM:SS format

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, timepicker

I want to put a time picker control on my web form. I'm using jQuery UI TimePicker (http://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/) in which I can achieve time selection in HH:MM format. However, I want a time picker for HH:MM:SS format so that I can directly save to MySql time field.

Because, I want to allow users to enter something like 23:59:59 or 18:00:01. So SS part is important.

Is there a time picker available to achieve this using a plug-in for jQuery or any script? Or how can I customize the one I'm currently using. I could not find any settings on that website.

Comment: we're not here to search google for you, nor are we here to tell you that you can trivially add `:00` to an hh:mm timestamp to turn it into hh:mm:ss.

Comment: Hey! you can trivially add :00 to an hh:mm timestamp to turn it into hh:mm:ss!

Comment: I want to something like 23:59:59. I'm just asking if anyone have come across any. If everything in Google we don't need this site, isn't it Marc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First hit from google "jquery timepicker" supports seconds: http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/

Also, the one you linked would be fairly easy to add seconds as a new column Header, but you would need to code it up yourself.  I suggest submitting the update back to the maintainer if you go that route.